# React Create 2D Array From Single Arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

I'm struggling to adapt to React.  I have two arrays.  Each item in one array must be matched to each item in another array.  From this, I need a 2D array.

This is what it would look like in C#:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var listA = new List<int>
            {
                11,12,13,14
            };
            var listB = new List<int>
            {
                21,22
            };
            var c = new List<Merged>();

            foreach(var i in listA)
            {
                foreach(var j in listB)
                {
                    Merged m = new Merged();
                    m.datasetId = i;
                    m.attributeId = j;
                    c.Add(m);
                }
            }
            foreach(var m in c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.datasetId + ", " + m.attributeId);
            }

            //OUTPUT
            //11, 21
            //11, 22
            //12, 21
            //12, 22
            //13, 21
            //13, 22
            //14, 21
            //14, 22

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class Merged
    {
        public int datasetId { get; set; }
        public int attributeId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific to React here, it's really just a Javascript question. You can use the same logic as your C# code:

```
const listA = [11, 12, 13, 14];
const listB = [21, 22];
let merged = [];

for (let i of listA) {
  for (let j of listB) {
    merged.push([i, j]);
  }
}

console.log(merged); // logs actual object
console.log(merged.map(pair => pair.join(", "))); // logs strings
```

### EDIT:

Here is one way to do this in a React class component, based on your comment. There are lots of different ways you could set this up, though, and depending on your data flow it may be better to put `listA` and `listB` into [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props) instead of state. Also, [function components with hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) are now very common and simpler in many cases than class components.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { listA: [11, 12, 13, 14], listB: [21, 22], merged: [] };

  mergeLists = () => {
    let newMerged = [];
    for (let i of this.state.listA) {
      for (let j of this.state.listB) {
        newMerged.push([i, j]);
      }
    }
    return newMerged.map(p => p.join(", "));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({merged: this.mergeLists()});
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (
        this.state.listA !== prevState.listA || 
        this.state.listB !== prevState.listB
    ) {
      this.setState({merged: this.mergeLists()})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.merged.map((pair, idx) => (
            <li key={idx}>{pair}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lederberg-seiu8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, it is same logic.  I'm having problems translating the same to React, something like:

```
export default class App extends Component {
state = {    
listA:  [11, 12, 13, 14],
listB: [21, 22],
merged: [],
pair: null
};

handleMix = () => {  
for (let i of listA) {
for (let j of listB) {
merged.push([i, j]);
}
}
pair = merged.map(p => p.join(", "))
this.setState({pair});
}
render()
{   
return (
<div><label>{this.Mix()}</label></div>    
)
}
}
```

Comment: I've added a React component example